# AMP page to regular HTML file redirection and Web version HTML file AMP file redirection?

Tags: url, amp-html

I am new to AMPs and already have designed amp page for my regular HTML web version without any errors. Now I have question which is about "specifying amp page in HTML file & regular file in AMP page".

1. Is my website URL require HTTPS connection? Or basic HTTP is enough?
2. while mentioning in `link` tag should I place `href` attribute value as `http://google.com/demo/index.html` or `/index.html` is enough?

Answer (score 1):

1. HTTP is enough unless you are serving content from your servers through extended components such as `<amp-video>` or `<amp-iframe>`.
2. You have to use the full URL, ie. `http://google.com/demo/index.html`, and not a relative URL path, ie. `/index.html`.

Comment: hi #Bagel, I made changes whatever you suggested to my question.Still I didn't get proper redirection on devices.can check my code (view source) by visiting following link     AMP page: http://moztech.in/demo/amp-index.html and regular web version    http://moztech.in/demo/index.html

Comment: AMP does not handle any redirection. Redirection should be handled on the server side. And I don't fully understand your question. Are you confused about why going to `moztech.in/demo/index.html` on a mobile device doesn't redirect you to the AMP page?

Comment: Yes Mr.butter-the-bagel .Everything was right in the code. when I access regular desktop version of HTML,crawler doesn't sending me to mobile AMP,vice versa also not happening.

Comment: I think there is a bit of misunderstanding here. The crawler does not do any redirection. All it does is it crawls or visits Web pages, indexes them, and caches the page if it is an AMP page.